# Why do I get a voltage spike when charging a capacitor through a diode?

Tags: simulation

I'm simulating simple circuit, where a small capacitor is charged through a 10R resistor and a diode. The capacitor can be discharged through a switch.

When the circuit is powered on, the switch is closed, the capacitor is not charging and current flows through the resistor and diode to "ground". When I open the switch, I expected the capacitor voltage to rise from 0 to 12V, where it should remain. Instead, as I open the switch, I'm getting a voltage spike over 20V, falling to 12V where it remains.

Can someone explain what happens there, when I open the switch, and how is it possible?

Edit: Without the diode, it behaves exactly as I've expected.

[image: Voltage spike on switch open]

I've tried [MultiSim](https://www.multisim.com/) and LTspice  as well as [Falstad Circuit simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) with similar results.

Comment: If the switch model has some inductance, it would cause some flyback voltage

Comment: The schematic shows 310 ohm and not 10 ohm as you said so, maybe there are other mistakes?

Comment: The switch used in simulation is a basic switch without any inductance.

Comment: There's 10ohm... '3' is only some mark on a wire, like '2', '1' and '0' below/at the top/at the left side, it doesn't belong to the resistor

Comment: For sure there must be some inductance hidden as a parasitic element in the circuit.  But you can try to reduce the effect by increasing the capacitor value.

Comment: @Andyaka '3' is the node number.

Comment: LTSpice is a simulator provided by Analog Devices. It isn't related to MultiSim.

Comment: Try reducing maximum timestep. How does the waveform change with this parameter? Try changing integration to GEAR (MAXORD = 2 or higher). How does the waveform change further? (Note Falstad only allows changing the fixed timestep; its numerical solver is simpler than SPICE's.)

Comment: The simulation is showing garbage at the output due to the limitation of a Trapezoidal rule or whatever method MultiSim is using. In Falstad we have a similar situation but we can "turn off" the Trapezoidal rule when click on the capacitor  https://tinyurl.com/2pdj4m5u

Comment: I am unable to duplicate this in LTspice using any of the integration methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulation is showing garbage at the output due to the limitation of a Trapezoidal rule or whatever method MultiSim is using.
In Falstad we have a similar situation [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0wIBxgCwGYBsl8FcB2LHEBSCiqhAUwFowwAoANxBwCZPsfuQXNGiijMVMDyrToCFgCdOuTIOEVMKoSInwWAEwr5VI3F01qeeugDMAhgFcANgBcWAYxDKqfKl85xRMEYATnBcaC5sTGZsPBxiSDRgpBg4VgBnEGIubxysvPFpcBA7R3S6FgB3T3EQHxqqLSgqhuNPMzbIFqJGtQQNTpbMZTaBJq4Wv0LWgS7qqb5efkW5mcXsqlmWjaX8zYDVnfqdpsO8pr9xlgBzXY0RAWGVaSHF+7uVlgB7cBUR-eCIjyqRSgl+dRYQA)

[image]

[image]

But we can "turn off" the Trapezoidal rule in Falstad.

Dubble-click on the capacitor

[image]

And thanks to this everything is backed to normal.

Comment: Thanks much for explanation, good to know that its a problem in the simulator, not in the circuit :-)